# Error creating user in Express routes file

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm creating a node app and I'm following the [nodepad example](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad) to create my users. However, I'm trying to do route separation and running into a problem when I try to open my /register page.

My app.js file looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
users = require('./routes/users'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb'),
util = require('util'),
models = require('./models'),
db,
User,
LoginToken,
Settings = { development: {}, test: {}, production: {} };

/**
 * Environments
 */

app.configure('development', function() {
  db = 'mongodb://localhost/db-development';
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true }));
  app.set('view options', {
    pretty: true
  });
});

app.configure('test', function() {
  db = 'mongodb://localhost/db-test';
  app.set('view options', {
    pretty: true
  });
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  db = 'mongodb://localhost/db-production';
});

console.log(db);

/**
 * Models Definitions
 */

models.defineModels(mongoose, function() {
  app.User = User = mongoose.model('User');
  app.LoginToken = LoginToken = mongoose.model('LoginToken');
});

mongoose.connect(db);

/**
 * All environments
 */

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ url: db, secret: 'secret' }));
});

...

// Sessions
app.post('/sessions', sessions.index);
app.get('/login', sessions.new);
app.del('/sessions', loadUser, sessions.del);

// Users

app.get('/register', users.register);
app.post('/users.:format?', users.registerprocess);
...
```

Then, my rote file looks someign like this:

```
exports.register = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User();
  res.render('users/new.jade', { flash: req.flash(),
                                  title: 'Register',
                                  bodyClass: 'registration',
                                  user: user});
};

exports.registerprocess = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body.user);

  function userSaveFailed() {
    req.flash('error', 'Account creation failed');
    res.render('users/new.jade', { flash: req.flash(),
                                   title: 'Register',
                                   bodyClass: 'registration',
                                   user: user });
  }

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return userSaveFailed();

    req.flash('info', 'Your account has been created');
    // emails.sendWelcome(user);

    switch (req.params.format) {
      case 'json':
        res.send(user.toObject());
      break;

      default:
        req.session.user_id = user.id;
        res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
};
```

When I try to go to /register, i get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: User is not defined
at module.exports.register (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/routes/users.js:2:18)
at callbacks (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
at param (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
at pass (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:49:5)
at next (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.logger (/Users/mmellado/workspace/project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:156:5)
```

Which makes me assume that for some reason, the User schema is not being found from the routes file. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you get a line number with that error, and, if so, can you separate out that line and add it to your question as an edit? In fact, you might post the whole stack trace.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full error. It marks the error on line 2, which is the `var user = new User()` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are placing the user on the app object, but you aren't requiring it in your other file. I'm not sure why you are choosing to define your models in your app.js, you should be defining them in their own file and they shouldn't know anything about your app instance.  Then in your route require your model. By placing the model on the app instance you're creating tight coupling when it really doesn't need to be.

Comment: So basically you are saying that my `models.defineModels(mongoose, function() {
  app.User = User = mongoose.model('User');
  app.LoginToken = LoginToken = mongoose.model('LoginToken');});` should go in the routes file instead of the server, without any need of adding the user to the app.... that actually makes a lot of sense... I will give that a try

Comment: Moving my model out of the server and using it from the routes file made a lot more sense and fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User is not defined. 
why you are sticking User to app is anyone's guess, but what you need to do is is have `app` available in your route's js file. You can require it there.

edit:
Looked at the example. In my option its not very good. They could have a better separation of routes from controllers and mongoose models are imported in a very weird way where you basically have to define them twice. Its more confusing then it needs to be.

Their example will be a pain in the ass to extend. I would find yourself some other example.

(yeah I know im not much help here, but its 230am and the best advice i can give you is to stay away from this crap if you are just starting out with node/mongoose/express)

Comment: I see your point. However I have used this exact same approach in other apps in the past and it had worked. The only difference is that in those apps I was using mongooseAuth for the authentication which makes me think there is something else I'm missing in my app :/

Comment: It seems to me that you are not very comfortable with how require works. The solution to your problem is very simple. you need to have `User` available in your file. It is attached to app so you must require app and do `user = new app.User()`. It is also evident to me that whoever wrote this example was also not very comfortable with require. This is a bad combination for you.

Comment: I'm totally fine using require, but my concern is this (and I might be wrong so please correct me if i am). Basically you are suggesting to do `var app = require('../app.js')` from inside routes/users.js, but app.js is already including users by doing `var users = require('routes/users)`. Wouldn't it be somehow redundant?

Comment: you mention that nodepad is not a good example... I know it's late but maybe tomorrow we can continue. In any case, can you guide me to a better example. All I'm trying to accomplish is a single login. I'm actually considering looking for a MySql alternative.